# How is the Bollinger Oscillator Calculated?

Tags: stocks, trading, algorithmic-trading

The Upperband is calculated: Middleband + (D + sqrt(((close - Middle band)^2)/n))

And I know how to calculate the lower bollinger band and middle bollinger bands.

But there is an elusive indicator called the bollinger oscillator which I find combines the bollinger bands into a single oscillating indicator. Please explain how to calculate it. 
Use SQL if possible assume fields contain relevant values.

Comment: Aren't Bollinger Bands the oscillator?

Comment: Bollinger bands are just standard deviations away from the 20-day moving average, The Bollinger Oscillator (BOS) gives the price relative to the bands. EG. when the price is above the upper band the BOS = (>2), below lower band = (<-2), so basically the number of standard deviations from the middle band (i think). Search for %B (which is a kind of bollinger oscillator) I have been unable to find the BOS though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the 9-day moving average average (n1 + n2 ... + n9)/9
2. Find the standard deviation of the 9-days
3. Subtract 9-day Moving average from the current ruling price
4. Take the answer devide by the standard deviation
5. Answer is the BOS (Bollinger Oscillator)